# Issue while deploying new revision of API

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I am having issue while deploying new revision of API with following error

```
 ERROR ApisApiServiceImpl Error while adding new API Revision for API : 22691636-953d-4929-adfc-977c3949bb05
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Failed to add revision registry artifacts
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.addAPIRevision_aroundBody550(APIProviderImpl.java:8850) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.addAPIRevision(APIProviderImpl.java:8824) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.addAPIRevision(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:1) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_9.20.74.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.impl.ApisApiServiceImpl.createAPIRevision(ApisApiServiceImpl.java:4177) ~[?:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.publisher.v1.ApisApi.createAPIRevision(ApisApi.java:339) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:201) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:104) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:307) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:265) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:225) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:304) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:217) ~[?:?]
```

I am using wso2 Api manager 4.1.0.

It was working fine and suddenly issue occurred. Now not able to deploy any new version or delete/modify that API.

Comment: Seems to be an issue with the Registry entries. Can you share how many WSO2 API Manager instances are running in your environment and how they are configured? Also, mention how the DBs are configured (whether you are using an RDBMS for the Registry DBs or have been using the default shipped H2 DBs as it is)

Comment: Only one instance of API manager is running with MySql DB

Comment: Have you configured all the DBs with MySQL? Or what are the DBs that are configured with the MySQL at present in your environment?

Comment: Yes i have used mysql for all DBs.

Comment: And also deployment of revision if working for default Pizzashack api. But not working for any other api which were working earlier.

Comment: If you are not seeing any other errors when trying to create a new revision of this API, then I suspect this might be due to corrupted Registry data in the API Manager. Can you check to create a new API and deploy a new revision?

Comment: Yes i have tried with that also. But all other new API have same problem. They are created successfully and whenever i tried to deploy new revision of that API that will create error.